# C: Do I need to cancel a thread I'm done using?

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm creating a thread in C to check something off a webpage ONCE during runtime. Am I suppose to CLOSE this thread, or once it's done executing will it automatically be disposed?

```
--> Imports
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

--> Start thread 
pthread_t thread_id;

pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, threadFunction, NULL);


---> Thread function

void *threadFunction(void *vargp) { 

    //Do something...
    
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: What threading library or standard are you using? (Showing us some code would be even more helpful.)

Comment: What does the documentation for your threading library say?

Comment: Look for a threading tutorial that discusses concepts of a joinable thread, a detached thread, and canceling a thread.

Comment: @jarmod Done, sorry about that. Brand new to C, so still figuring out the basics

Comment: In a nutshell, it is often sufficient to create detached threads, and allow the threads to exit. If it is important to know when a thread exits, you create joinable threads, and then the main thread waits on them to exit with a join. Thread cancel is rarely used, but can be used if a thread is blocked or deadlocked on a cancelation point.

Comment: Passing in NULL for your thread attributes means you are creating joinable threads (the default). So, you need to call join on each of them, or automate the joining by having the main thread call `pthread_exit`. Or detach them explicitly with `pthread_detach`.

Comment: @jxh Thank you! That's exactly the information I needed.

Comment: Note that joinable threads are almost always what you want to use, and joining them explicitly, at an appropriate point, is usually what you want to do.  Do not detach threads at least until you have a reasonably good grasp of what that means and does.  Do not cancel threads at all -- or at least not until you are confident that you know what you are doing well enough to safely ignore other people's well-informed advice.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to consider using `pthread_cancel` unless the goal is to prematurely end the execution of a running thread.

In most cases, you are just wanting the thread to complete its work. You normally detect that a thread has completed by joining with it, using `pthread_join`.

If you are creating a thread that is not expected to end, or it doesn't matter when it ends, you can create a detached thread, or detach it after creation using `pthread_detach`. Then, the thread is not joinable.

Your sample code passes in `NULL` for the thread attributes, which causes `pthread_create` to use default attributes. You should check your system, but Linux will create joinable threads by default.

For most beginner projects, it is probably easiest to create joinable threads, and have the main thread call `pthread_exit` after spawning all the threads. This waits for each spawned thread to finish executing before the program terminates.

Otherwise, if there is summary work that the main thread needs to perform after the threads complete, it would wait on each thread with `pthread_join` until all the threads have returned. After the last thread returns, the main thread can do what it needs to do, and then exit.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for pthread says this:

The thread is created executing start_routine with arg as its sole argument. If the start_routine returns, the effect shall be as if there was an implicit call to pthread_exit() using the return value of start_routine as the exit status. Note that the thread in which main() was originally invoked differs from this. When it returns from main(), the effect shall be as if there was an implicit call to exit() using the return value of main() as the exit status.

So there is no need to explicitly terminate thread.

Comment: There are still resources that need to be cleaned up for joinable threads (with `pthread_join`), otherwise you're left with a "zombie thread"